# phone number in json foursquare api

Tags: asp.net, json, api, foursquare

i have a json returned from foursquare to get the nearby gym i just wanna know if it may return several phone numbers for the same gym and if it is the case i need to know the format of the numbers... are they separated by "," or being displayed in several tags?

```
"categories": [
            {
                "id": "4bf58dd8d48988d16e941735",
                "name": "Fast Food Restaurant",
                "pluralName": "Fast Food Restaurants",
                "shortName": "Fast Food",
                "icon": {
                    "prefix": "https://ss1.4sqi.net/img/categories_v2/food/fastfood_",
                    "suffix": ".png"
                },
                "primary": true
            }
        ]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is only one phone number associated with each venue. You can find `phone` and `formattedPhone` responses in the `contact` field for a venue. Example: https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/explore#req=venues/4be30f9dd27a20a1cd1f915b